# Dynamics 365 On premise calculate chain limitation ease?

Tags: dynamics-365

I have Dynamics 365 V8.2.

I want to know if there are any ways (supported or unsupported) to ease the limitation chain of calculation field from 5?

I have a solution which contains fields of more than 5 chains! and when I try to change one of them it gives an error about

You can't create or update the my_field_name field because the myentitynameid !!!! field already has a calculated field chain of 5!
which is not correct and it refers to the id field which certainly is not a caluclated field.

Best